# Is maxpooling on odd number possible?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I am going through the Udacity DeepLearning Nanodegree and working on the autoencoder mini project.  I do not understand the solution, nor how to check it myself.  So this is 2 questions.

We start with 28*28 images.  These are fed through 3 convolutional layers, each with padding of 1, and each with a maxpooling to half the original dimensions.  What I don't understand is the last element?  Surely 2 rounds of maxpooling (28/2)/2 gives 7 and therefore a further maxpooling shouldn't be possible as it results in an odd number.  Can someone explain why this is the case to me?  The code to replicate is here:
'''

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

# convert data to torch.FloatTensor
transform = transforms.ToTensor()

# load the training and test datasets
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False,
                                  download=True, transform=transform)

# Create training and test dataloaders
num_workers = 0
# how many samples per batch to load
batch_size = 20

# prepare data loaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

# define the NN architecture
class ConvDenoiser(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvDenoiser, self).__init__()
        ## encoder layers ##
        # conv layer (depth from 1 --> 32), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, padding=1)  
        # conv layer (depth from 32 --> 16), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 16, 3, padding=1)
        # conv layer (depth from 16 --> 8), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, padding=1)
        # pooling layer to reduce x-y dims by two; kernel and stride of 2
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

        ## decoder layers ##
        # transpose layer, a kernel of 2 and a stride of 2 will increase the spatial dims by 2
        self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 8, 3, stride=2)  # kernel_size=3 to get to a 7x7 image output
        # two more transpose layers with a kernel of 2
        self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 16, 2, stride=2)
        self.t_conv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 32, 2, stride=2)
        # one, final, normal conv layer to decrease the depth
        self.conv_out = nn.Conv2d(32, 1, 3, padding=1)


    def forward(self, x):
        ## encode ##
        # add hidden layers with relu activation function
        # and maxpooling after
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        # add second hidden layer
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        # add third hidden layer
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.pool(x)  # compressed representation

        ## decode ##
        # add transpose conv layers, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.t_conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.t_conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.t_conv3(x))
        # transpose again, output should have a sigmoid applied
        x = F.sigmoid(self.conv_out(x))

        return x

# initialize the NN
model = ConvDenoiser()
print(model)
```

I wanted to try to understand this by passing a single image through the layers manually and see what the result was but this resulted in an error.  Can someone explain to me how I can see the shapes that pass through the layers?  Code is a bit messy but I left it there so you can see what I tried.

```
dataiter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
# images = images.numpy()

# get one image from the batch
# img = np.squeeze(images[0])
img=images[0]

#create hidden layer
conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, padding=1)  

# z=torch.from_numpy(images[0])
z1=conv1(img)
```

Appreciate any insights you can give me.
Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first question:
You can read in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#maxpool2d) how the output shape of max-pooling is computed. You can max-pool odd-shaped tensors with even strides with or without padding. You need to be careful about the boundaries where some pixels may be lost.

---

Regarding your second question:
Your model expects a 4D input: batch-channel-height-width.
By selecting only one image from the batch (`img=images[0]`) you eliminate the batch dimension ending up with only a 3D tensor.
To fix this:

```py
img=images[0:1, ...]  # select first image, but leave batch dimension as a singleton
```

Comment: The hint on the second question helped.  Changed img to be 0:20 images and then ran it.  Will check out the documentations about the maxpool dimensions.  Thank you